# MVC.Net sending "<>" tags to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Our MVC.Net application is sometimes returning tags with no content.  More specifically, with nothing between the `<` and `>`.  Bringing up the IE-8 developer tools to examine the returned HTML reveals a no-name tag: `<>` and its closing tag: `</>`.  The problem is intermittent.  Usually, refreshing the page will clear the problem.  But it is frequent enough and users are complaining enough that management wants it fixed.

**When the problem occurs the browser's HTML source looks like this:**

```html
<TR sizcache="5" sizset="47">
    <TD class="label table-col-3">
        Manager:
    </TD>
    <TD class="table-col-7 last" sizcache="5" sizset="49">
        <A href="http://localhost:57791/Profile/22/Last%2c-First-MI" jQuery1359570774586="26">Last, First MI</A> 
    </TD>
</TR>
<>
  <div>
  </div>
</>
```

**Normally, the browser's HTML should look like this:**

```html
<TR sizcache="5" sizset="47">
    <TD class="label table-col-3">
        Manager:
    </TD>
    <TD class="table-col-7 last" sizcache="5" sizset="49">
        <A href="http://localhost:57791/Profile/22/Last%2c-First-MI" jQuery1359570774586="26">Last, First MI</A> 
    </TD>
</TR>
<TR id="link-admin-assistant-28" data-update="type: 'replace-portion', dataType: 'html', target: 'link-admin-assistant-28', source: 'link-admin-assistant-28'" sizcache="5" sizset="51">
    <TD class="label table-col-3">
        Admin Assistant:
    </TD>
    <TD class="table-col-7 last" sizcache="5" sizset="53">
        <A title="Edit Administrative Assistant" href="http://localhost:57791/Person/AdminAssistantForm?clientID=28" jQuery1359570774586="27">Last2, First2 M2</A> 
    </TD>
</TR>
<TR sizcache="5" sizset="55">
    <TD class="label table-col-3">
        Type:
    </TD>
    <TD class="table-col-7 last">
        Employee 
    </TD>
</TR>
```

**App Details**

The app was built with MVC.Net 2.  We've since upgraded to using .Net 4.0.  There is also plenty of JQuery for client-side scripting and handling AJAX calls.

As the views' *.ascx pages only contain well-formed HTML5, interspersed with server-side code fragements, I don't see how the web-server is returning "<>" tags.

The problem occurs somewhere after the manager and matrix manager IF block.  When the problem occurs, the EmployeeType is not displayed.

**Section of code where I think the problem occurs**
(based upon visible HTML in IE's dev-tools)

```html
<% if (managerPersonID != null && managerPersonID > 0 && !managerDisplayName.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed()) { %>
<tr>
    <td class="label table-col-3">Manager:</td>
    <td class="table-col-7 last"><%--<a href="<%=Url.Action("Details", new { ID = manager.PersonID, Name = manager.DisplayName, GAL = "" })%>"><%=manager.DisplayName%></a>--%>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(managerDisplayName, "Details", "Person", new { ID = managerPersonID, Name = managerDisplayName.Replace(" ", "-"), GAL = "" }, new {}) %>
        <%--Matrix Manager--%>
        <% if (matrixPersonID != null && matrixPersonID > 0 && !matrixDisplayName.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed()) { %>
            <span class="label">&#8212; Matrix:</span>
            <%--<a href="<%=Url.Action("Details", new { ID = matrixManager.PersonID, Name = matrixManager.DisplayName, GAL = "" }) %>"><%=matrixManager.DisplayName%></a>--%>
            <%= Html.ActionLink(matrixDisplayName, "Details", "Person", new { ID = matrixPersonID, Name = matrixDisplayName.Replace(" ", "-"), GAL = "" }, new {}) %>
        <% } %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>

<!-- Error seems to occur somewhere after here -->

<%--Sponsoring Manager--%>
<% if (Model.SponsoringManagerPersonID != null && Model.SponsoringManagerPersonID > 0 && !Model.SponsoringManagerDisplayName.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed()) { %>
<tr>
    <td class="label table-col-3">Sponsor:</td>
    <td class="table-col-7 last">
        <%--<a href="<%=Url.Action("Details", new { ID = Model.SponsoringManager.PersonID, Name = Model.SponsoringManager.DisplayName, GAL = "" })%>"><%=Model.SponsoringManager.DisplayName%></a>--%>
        <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.SponsoringManagerDisplayName, "Details", "Person", new { ID = Model.SponsoringManagerPersonID, Name = Model.SponsoringManagerDisplayName.Replace(" ", "-"), GAL = "" }, new {}) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>

<%-- Administrative Assistant --%>
<% Html.RenderPartial("AdminAssistant", Model.AdministrativeAssistant); %>

<%--Employee Type--%>
<tr>
    <td class="label table-col-3">Type:</td>
    <td class="table-col-7 last">
        <%= Enum.GetName(typeof(Person.PersonType), Model.EmployeeType ?? (int)Person.PersonType.Default) %>
    </td>
</tr>

 <!-- Error appears to occur somewhere before here -->
```

**AdminAssistant Partial View**

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AdminAssistantLink>" %>
<%
    bool IsProfileView = ((bool?)ViewData["IsProfileView"]) ?? false;
    string AdminAssistLinkID = "link-admin-assistant-" + Model.ProfilePersonID;
%>
<%-- Administrative Assistant --%>
<% if (IsProfileView && Role.AllowProfileEditSpecific(Model.ProfilePersonID)) { %>
    <%--Edit mode--%>
    <tr id="<%= AdminAssistLinkID %>" data-update="type: 'replace-portion', dataType: 'html', target: '<%= AdminAssistLinkID %>', source: '<%= AdminAssistLinkID %>'">
        <td class="label table-col-3">Admin Assistant:</td>
        <td class="table-col-7 last">
            <% if (Model.AdminAssistantPersonID != null && !Model.AdminAssistantDisplayName.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed()) { %>
                <%-- Display currently selected assistant, with link to edit --%>
                <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.AdminAssistantDisplayName, "AdminAssistantForm", "Person", new { clientID = Model.ProfilePersonID }, new { title = "Edit Administrative Assistant" }) %>
            <% } else { %>
                <%-- Display link to add assistant --%>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Add Administrative Assistant", "AdminAssistantForm", "Person", new { clientID = Model.ProfilePersonID }, new {title = "Add Administrative Assistant" }) %>
            <% } %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } else { %>
    <%--Link to Profile--%>
    <% if (Model.AdminAssistantPersonID != null && !Model.AdminAssistantDisplayName.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed()) { %>
    <tr>
        <td class="label table-col-3">Admin Assistant:</td>
        <td class="table-col-7 last">
            <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.AdminAssistantDisplayName, "Details", "Person", new { ID = Model.AdminAssistantPersonID, Name = Model.AdminAssistantDisplayName.Replace(" ", "-"), GAL = "" }, new {}) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Can we see the code inside the AdminAssistant partial?

Comment: Can you include more of your Html?  There's also no `<div>` blocks in the code behind you included, so I don't know why they're showing up in your output.

Comment: I don't know why they are showing up either.  When the page works, those <div> tags are not present.  When it fails, they are.

Comment: @Zarepheth - If you're still having this problem, can you include more of the HTML that's being output?  I still can't tell where in the ASPX the output you're getting is coming from.  Ideally, you can show us everything from the Manager `tr` to the type `tr`, since that's the code you shared.

Comment: @Bobson - Let me see what I can do.  As the problem is intermittent, I've not been able to reproduce it recently, but I should be able to post the expected HTML to the browser.

Comment: @Bobson - I've added the expected HTML and expanded the unexpected HTML.  Perhaps you can see why I'm confused...  I don't see anything obvious that could cause the results seen when the problem occurs.

Comment: @Zarepheth - I'm even more stumped now.  Everything looks right to me, and I can't see any reason that it would be intermittent (assuming consistent data).  Does it happen or not each time you refresh, or is it more on-and-off by day?

Comment: @Bobson - it is intermittent.  On the production system, while doing lookups for a different issue, this one popped up.  I looked up the HTML source and got the same results.  However, this time in IE's developer tools, I right-click on the `<table>` element and copied the Inner and Outer HTML.  Upon pasting in text editor, the `<>` and `</>` elements were missing, but the `<div></div>` was still located inside the `<table>` but outside any `<tr>` or `<td>` tags.  I'm not sure this means anything, could just that IE Dev Tools renders malformed HTML differently in different places.

Comment: @Bobson - After getting the data for my previous comment, I refreshed the page and everything rendered properly.  IE's Dev Tools showed properly formed HTML and everything looked fine, no `<>` tags and no `<div>` tags hanging out inside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is your comment tags?  Are these legal razor syntax?

```
<%--Sponsoring Manager--%>
...
<%-- Administrative Assistant --%>
...
<%--Employee Type--%>
```

I don't have an MVC 2 site to test with, so I don't know how they will display.
In MVC 3, the tags are shown in the browser markup as-is.

Comment: Razor wasn't introduced until MVC 3.  This is the webforms template syntax, so those comments should be fine.

Comment: @beezir - good call. I just did confirm in a test project that the above tags are indeed legit comment tags in MVC2.

Comment: As @beezir notes, we're not using Razor.  In Visual Studio, they get high-lighted as server-side comments.